# scroll image doesn't work

Tags: javascript, html, css

The following codes are not working as intended.

index.html

```css
#header {
  z-index: 2;
  height: 90px;
  width: 100%;
  min-width: 1060px;
}
#footer {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 2;
}
#top-wrapper {
  overflow-x: auto;
}
#main-content {
  min-width: 1060px;
  position: absolute;
  overflow-y: auto;
}
#image-wrapper {
  padding-left: 20%;
  padding-right: 20%;
  width: 100%;
  height: 500px;
}
#coordinations {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 500px;
}
```

```html
<div id="top-wrapper">
  <div id="header">
    <!-- some nav menu -->
  </div>
  <div id="main-content">
    <div id="image-wrapper"></div>
    <div id="coordinations"></div>
  </div>
  <div id="footer">
    <!-- some footer note -->
  </div>
</div>
```

The problem here is my scroll has the invisible #coordination div, which I can't make it into zero or get rid of (since it has all the coordinations I need to use on the #image-wrapper div).

I tried to make invisible div on top #main-content div, so use the overflow-y but it doesn't work. I tried to contain #main-content inside a bigger div and min-height to some x value. Still it doesn't work.

Any possible way I can have #image-wrapper without the invisible content from #coordinations?

**Update**

```
#coordinations
{
position:relative;
width:100%;
height:0px;
}
```

Sorry I didn't see this, but by changing position to relative and height to 0px. The coordination points or children of #coordinations are not affected.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: The only way to completely hide an element would be to add `display: none` to it. `visibility:hidden` just hides it, but it still takes the space. `opacity: 0` will only make the element 100% transparent, it is still there and clickable.

Comment: Thanks Pol, the `display:none` works great but I lose all the information in the child div. The other two doesn't make any changes to it. I feel like pulling my hair right now haha, it looks like there is no other way to solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

You already have `#coordinations` set as `display: absolute`, why not just move it off-screen with a `left: -9999px;`?

Comment: `#main-content` still sees the child div `#coordinations`, and by shifting #coordinations off screen all the children div are also shifted off screen. Sorry, I can't use this :(.

Comment: No worries. I don't really understand what content is going into the `#coordinations` div and why it can't simply be set to `display: none` or shifted off-screen. Perhaps some more information and sample content in your question would make it clearer and someone will be able to help.